# Running Docker on windows 8, FORBIDDEN ERROR

Tags: windows, windows-8, docker, boot2docker, dockerhub

I installed boot2docker on windows 8 and all the other dependencies (virtualbox and git bash). When i click on the boot2docker shortcut it works fine, setting all the environment variables , and docker runs successfully . please see below to see what the error is:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d

$ docker run hello-world
An error occurred trying to connect: Post   https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.19/containers/create: Forbidden
```